# Drupal 7 Adding poll to forum topic or article

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there any way I can add poll to forum topic (Advance forum) or/And Article/Basic page.
I m still evaluating poll modules .. feel free to suggest best poll module other than core one.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use Pollfield module, but It's not a final version:

https://drupal.org/project/pollfield

Regards.